# POS.NET discovering pos printers

Tags: opos, pos-for-.net

I use PosExplorer.GetDevices method to look for printers available on network. However, the DeviceInfo object in the DeviceCollection returned by GetDevices() method does not include information on LogicalNames, HardwareId, HardwarePath.

In my app, I need to discover available printers and create an instance of those printers.

I am using epson t88iv printers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Sean Liming for the reply
(http://www.seanliming.com/)

POS for .NET can only be used for devices connected locally to the system via a service object. It cannot be used to find devices on a network unless you have a service object that will interact with a network printer.