# Find (POS) Printer on Local host?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I am working on Manage Restaurants order web application. Web site is working fine. But problem arise when find PRINTER on local host. I am using Virtual Printer.

```
private PosPrinter GetReceiptPrinter()
{
    PosExplorer posExplorer = new PosExplorer();

    DeviceInfo receiptPrinterDevice = posExplorer.GetDevice("PosPrinter", "TwoPilotsDemoPrinter"); 

    return (PosPrinter)posExplorer.CreateInstance(receiptPrinterDevice);
}
```

Problem aries when we find Printer on Local Host i.e     **posExplorer.GetDevice("PosPrinter", "TwoPilotsDemoPrinter");**

Do anyone have any experience with the same.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: when we find virtual printer device in our local host than It   "posExplorer.GetDevice("PosPrinter", "TwoPilotsDemoPrinter")" retrun device null value.

Comment: I don't think helpful, but related  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14720986/pos-net-discovering-pos-printers